# Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php

I'm getting the following error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

I am using php5.5.34.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
if($queryaddress_select_user_basic_info = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user_basic_info WHERE            username = '$valusername_registerphp'"))
{
    if($count = $queryaddress_select_user_basic_info->num_rows)
    {
        while($valuesinloop_userbasicinfo = $queryaddress_select_user_basic_info->fetch_object())
        {
            echo $valuesinloop_userbasicinfo->username,'<br>';
            echo $_SESSION['user_primaryvalue'] =$valuesinloop_userbasicinfo; //error is on this line

        }
    }

    else
    {
        echo "cannot count results/cannot return results";
    }
}

else
{
    echo "query not written correctly!";
}
?>
```

Any ideas why it's throwing an error?

Comment: Indent your code properly, and use prepared statements instead of string concatenation. Also, please show which line that error occurs on

Comment: You can't `echo` an arbitrary object and get anything meaningful.

Comment: @Bojangles I'm assuming it's on this line: `echo $valuesinloop_userbasicinfo->username,'<br>';` @OP: Try using `var_dump($valuesinloop_userbasicinfo->username);`, it'll probably say it's an object.

Answer (score 0):

`$valuesinloop_userbasicinfo` is an object. You're setting the value of a session to that object (which works fine) but do mind that setting a variable will also return its value.

`echo $_SESSION['user_primaryvalue'] =$valuesinloop_userbasicinfo;`

This line will not only set the value of `$_SESSION['user_primaryvalue']` but also `echo` it and considering `$_SESSION['user_primaryvalue']` is now an object it will cause the given error.